# xpath: count preceding elements

Tags: xpath

I have an xml structure that looks like this:

```
<document>
    <body>
        <section>
            <title>something</title>
            <subtitle>Something again</subtitle>
            <section>
                <p xml:id="1234">Some text</p>
                <figure id="2121"></figure>
                <section>
                    <p xml:id="somethingagain">Some text</p>
                    <figure id="939393"></figure>
                    <p xml:id="countelement"></p>
                </section>
            </section>
        </section>
        <section>
            <title>something2</title>
            <subtitle>Something again2</subtitle>
            <section>
                <p xml:id="12345678">Some text2</p>
                <figure id="939394"></figure>
                <p xml:id="countelement2"></p>
            </section>
        </section>
    </body>
</document>
```

How can I count the figure elemtens I have before the `<p xml:id="countelement"></p>` element using XPath?

**Edit:**
And i only want to count figure elements within the parent section, in the next section it should start from 0 again.

Comment: Could you check your formatting? The element name is not visible.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I have changed it now :)

Comment: What's the expected output for this input? Shall there be two results or only one (second is called `countelement2`). Result for the first `countelement` is 1 or 2? The second isn't 'within the parent section'. What XPath engine are you using (and does it support XPath 2.0)?

Comment: The expected output in "countelement" is 2 (or 1 if starting from 0) and in "countelement2" it is 1 (or 0). I use Arbortext Styler.

Answer (score 1):

Given you're using an **XPath 2.0 compatible engine**, find the count element and call `fn:count()` for each of them with using all preceding figure-elements as input.

This will return the number of figures preceding each "countelement" on the same level (I guess this is what you actually want):

```
//p[@xml:id="countelement"]/count(preceding-sibling::figure)
```

This will return the number of figures preceding each "countelement" and the level above:

```
//p[@xml:id="countelement"]/count(preceding-sibling::figure | parent::*/preceding-sibling::figure)
```

This will return the number of all preceeding figures preceding each "countelement" and the level above:

```
//p[@xml:id="countelement"]/count(preceding::figure)
```

---

If you're bound to **XPath 1.0**, you won't be able to get multiple results. If `@id` really is an id (and thus unique), you will be able to use this query:

```
count(//p[@xml:id="countelement"]/preceding::figure)
```

---

*If there are "countelements" which are not `<p/>` elements, replace `p` by `*`.*

Comment: Your second example almost works. However, it doesnt "stop" counting - i only want to count objects within the current level 1 section.

Comment: Seems I still don't get which figures to count. Would you give me the figure `id`s for each count element?

Comment: I want to count how many figures there are within the first section element in total. And later how many figure elements there are within the level 2 section element.

Comment: The second query is counting exactly these elements. You didn't provide the IDs for the second count element.

Comment: Second ids: 939394. The counter counts all preceding figure elements.

Comment: My second query exactly counts these elements and thus returns "2" respective "1".

Comment: Is there anywhere i can post my entire XML structure for you to have a look at?

Comment: [gist](https://gist.github.com/) ist great for doing that. If you do so, please update your question and include in detail what output is expected. Please do not only provide the numbers, but also which IDs to count. And do not post several megabytes of data, just an example large enough to work with if the one in your question isn't yet.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/aaanderss/1304aebb75f0596acf18   I want to count the all figures within the first section level. In this document there are two sections on the first levels.

Comment: This doesn't seem very connected to your question above... Are you looking for `//body/section/count(.//figure)` (counting all figures for each first-level section) or `//body/section[1]/count(.//figure)` counting all figures only within the first first-level section?

Comment: I am looking for an xpath to count all figures within the first level section (then the second one)

Comment: Sorry, seems I don't get you, giving up on this now. Seems nobody else is either, usually questions tagged XPath get answered within minutes. If you still want an answer, read about [ask], more hints in [this longer version](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Put everything into the question which is important (and update this when giving more details in comments). Write about your _real_ problem, tell us what you did to achieve this, where are you stuck? Include expected output. Chances are very high you will get a satisfying answer then.

Answer (score 0):

`count(id("countelement")/preceding-sibling::figure)`

Please note that the `xml:id` attributes of two different elements cannot the same value, such as "countelement". If you wish two different elements to have a same-named attribute with the same value "countelement", it must be some other attribute perhaps "kind" that is not of DTD attribute type ID. In that case in place of `id("countelement")` you would use `*[@kind="countelement"]`.